# Blender spotlight strength in millions before visible?

Tags: light, lighting, scale

I am trying to make a spotlight illuminate a scene. I have removed the linked background so that there is no ambient light but the following render depicts this spotlight at about a strength of 4.5 million. Any ideas of how it got like this and how to get it to a normal range?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your model is too big (meaning much larger than the scale in the real world)? Blender is designed to work with scales that resemble those of the real object. If your objects are too big then it makes sense that you need very bright sources to illuminate large areas. In any case, if you are getting the results you want there is nothing wrong with using large values. Beware though that depth of field and physics might not work correctly if your scene is huge.